# Cannot build adal4j library from source

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, sharepoint, adal

- Ubuntu 15.04
- Eclipse Mars
- Oracle Java 1.7 JRE

Hi

I'm afraid this is a real noob question but I'm really stuck and need to get this working.

I am trying to write a small Java application which will upload a file to SharePoint Online using the REST interface and I'm having trouble getting it to authenticate.

A bit of research pointed me to the adal4j library on github (https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java) but I've fallen at the first stage; getting the library to build.

I downloaded the source and used the top level pom.xml with Maven and the goals 'clean install' but the build fails with lots of messages similar to this one...

`AdalAccessTokenResponseTest.java:[27,34] com.microsoft.azure.adal4j.AdalAccessTokenResponse is not public in com.microsoft.azure.adal4j; cannot be accessed from outside package`

I have a  tar.gz of all the messages I can provide if necessary.

This is a perfect storm for me, I'm new to Java, new to Eclipse, new to Maven, new to Sharepoint Online, and new to RESTful services - It's safe to say I've been chucked in the deep end!

Can anyone help please?

Comment: have you tried building the product from command line using maven? try "mvn clean package"

Comment: Tried it from command line. It builds fine, several warnings, but it builds. Running Linux, tried both Java7 and Java8.

Comment: Thank you both, building from the command line worked and I have the Jar files I need.